# Alternative Checkout Method for Shopify?

Tags: shopify

Is there a way to redirect the "Proceed to Checkout" button in the Shopify cart to another system to process the sale?  The fact that developers/designers have no access whatsoever to this last part of the sales process means that even the slightest change becomes an unsurmountable problem. Does anyone know if it would be possible to replace this last stage with another system?

Comment: No. It is a hosted system. If you feel like you need to do your own checkout there are plenty of free e-commerce software projects you can use for that. Better yet, roll your own, then you have nothing to complain about! Have fun, play safe, and watch out for those crafty Elbonians as they try and hack your cart.

Answer (score 3):

The checkout flow is hosted to allow for PCI compliance via Shopify. Shopify uses a single domain for processing the checkouts on `checkout.shopify.com` because of this it is not possible to customize a single checkout page, only the css. There is however a method to the madness. PCI compliance is a requirement for most payment gateway interfacing software and quarterly audits are usually required. If Shopify allowed these steps to be changed it would likely break their PCI compliance and cause all sorts of issues.

I don't think this was a design mistake but rather a trade off to have the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible. The only alternatives are to use Google Wallet (AKA Checkout) or PayPal for checkout.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame. The checkout process is the weakest link of an otherwise highly customizable, flexible shopping cart system. Big design oversight, IMHO.